# Video is not playing correctly using Red5, rtmp, and jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, rtmp, red5

I have a Red5 server running. I am trying to stream a video file from a custom path. I think I have all or most of my server code correct. I am trying to test it with the following test html code:

```
<html>


 <head>
    <script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/xxxxxx.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">This will be replaced by the jwplayer</div>
    <script>
      jwplayer("container").setup({
        file:  "rtmp://localhost:1935/streaming/files/testVid.mp4",
        height: 360,
        width: 640,
        autostart: true,
        rtmp: {
            bufferlength: 3
        }
      });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/streaming/test.html a jwplayer is displayed as expected. However when I press play, the video does not start.

It gets stuck at time 0:00. If I click on the seek-bar on a section that is already buffered it will start playing. When it starts playing it plays extremely slow and choppy. The time on the left of the seek-bar is still incriminating normally though (in real time even though the video itself is in major slow-mo). What ends up happening is my 50 second test video ends up taking about 20 mins to play, so I end with 20:00 on the left of the seek-bar and 0:50 on the right.

Also there is no sound. I checked and the audio has AAC Codec.

Also after I click play I get the following lines in my console.

> [INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-3] org.red5.io.mp4.impl.MP4Reader -
>   Entry: Entry{firstChunk=1, samplesPerChunk=1,
>   sampleDescriptionIndex=1}
>
> [INFO] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-3] org.red5.io.mp4.impl.MP4Reader -
>   Audio decoder bytes were not available
>
> [INFO] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-24]
>   com.my.project.path.stream.app.StreamingApplication - W3C
>   x-category:stream x-event:play c-ip:10.1.10.239
>   x-sname:1559e5b9-87e4-4610-850c-b928760f5fed x-name:testVid

**1) Why is my video playing so slow?**

**2) Why is there no sound?**

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some URL to debug your issue, you can use https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: what jwplayer version are you using ?

Comment: I am using version 7.7.4. I wasn't able to get a URL using jsfiddle.net because I am using Java not JavaScript for the server. @Hitesh